# Image Being rotated after compression

Tags: java, android, image

last time i asked a question about how to reduce the size of an image before uploading it to the server, the assistance you gave me was great the picture's size decreased from (2-3 mbs) to 200-300kbs, but the problem is the picture is being rotated by 90 degrees, can you please help me.
This is the Class

```
public class ScalingUtilities {

public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
            dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    return unscaledBitmap;
}
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
            dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return unscaledBitmap;
}

public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
            dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
            dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;
}

public static enum ScalingLogic {
    CROP, FIT
}

public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                      ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            return srcWidth / dstWidth;
        } else {
            return srcHeight / dstHeight;
        }
    } else {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            return srcHeight / dstHeight;
        } else {
            return srcWidth / dstWidth;
        }
    }
}
public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
            final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
            return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
        } else {
            final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
            final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
            return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
        }
    } else {
        return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
    }
}
public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
                                    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
        final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
        }
    } else {
        return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
    }
}
```

}

and this is the function used in the application

```
private String decodeFile(String path,int DESIREDWIDTH, int DESIREDHEIGHT) {
    String strMyImagePath = null;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
    try {
        // Part 1: Decode image
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeFile(path, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingUtilities.ScalingLogic.FIT);

        if (!(unscaledBitmap.getWidth() <= DESIREDWIDTH && unscaledBitmap.getHeight() <= DESIREDHEIGHT)) {
            scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingUtilities.ScalingLogic.FIT);
        } else {
            unscaledBitmap.recycle();
            return path;
        }
        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File mFolder = new File(extr + "/MyImages");
        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            mFolder.mkdir();
        }

        String s = imageFileName+".jpg";

        File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);

        strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        scaledBitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }

    if (strMyImagePath == null) {
        return path;
    }
    return strMyImagePath;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExifInterface` for your `strMyImagePath`

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(strMyImagePath);
    int exifRotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    switch (exifRotation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
            photoRotation = 90.0f;
            break;
        }
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
            photoRotation = 180.0f;
            break;
        }
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
            photoRotation = 270.0f;
            break;
        }
    }
```

and put `postRotate` for Matrix and create `Bitmap` with your Existing `Bitmap`

```
int w = bitmap.getWidth();
int h = bitmap.getHeight();
Matrix mat = new Matrix();

mat.postRotate(photoRotation);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mat, true);
```

Comment: where is the float photoRotation useD?